# R data.table lapply with cut function

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I'm trying to group data with pre-determined breakpoints by year. I can easily do this with the `cut()` function for a given year, but I'm struggling to get it to work within the `data.table` function. Here is the test data:

```
set.seed(4)
YR = data.table(yr=1962:2015)
ID = data.table(id=10001:11000)
DT <- YR[,as.list(ID), by = yr] # intentional cartesian join
# now add data
DT[,`:=` (ratio = rep(sample(10),each=2700)+rnorm(nrow(DT)))]
```

That gives three columns: yr, id, and ratio, with the latter being the data I want to group.

Now here are the yearly breakpoints:

```
DTy <- data.table(matrix(rep(1:10,each=nrow(YR)),nrow(YR),10)+rnorm(54)/10)
DTy[,yr := 1962:2015]
```

So for each year from 1962 to 2015 there is a set of cutoffs. To use 1962 as an example, here is what I'd like to do:

```
group <- cut(DT[yr==1962,ratio],DTy[yr==1962, -c("yr")], labels = FALSE)
```

And here is what it should look like.

```
ratio <- DT[yr==1962,ratio]
DTy[yr==1962,-c("yr")]
test <- data.table(ratio,group)
test[,yr:=1962]
> test
         ratio group   yr
   1: 6.689275     6 1962
   2: 4.718753     4 1962
   3: 5.786855     5 1962
   4: 7.896540     7 1962
   5: 7.776863     7 1962
  ---                    
 996: 6.176614     6 1962
 997: 7.689046     7 1962
 998: 4.652658     4 1962
 999: 7.075622     7 1962
1000: 5.543791     5 1962
```

I tried this:

```
# merge two datasets together
newDT <- merge(x = DT, y = DTy, by = c("yr"))
# get names of columns with breakpoints
cnames <- names(newDT)[newDT[,grep("^V", names(newDT))]] 
# apply the cut function by year. 
newDT[,groupt := lapply(.SD, cut, as.vector(unique(.SD[,cnames,with=FALSE])), labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE), by = .(year), .SDcols = c("ratio", cnames)]
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(newDT, , `:=`(groupt, lapply(.SD, cut, as.vector(unique(.SD[,  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type closure. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

I'm honestly not sure what that means. I'm trying to use .SD like a data.table but need different columns for different parts of the `cut()` function and I'm not sure how to pass them via `lapply`.

Comment: Both are great solutions - I like the second one because it is closest to what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got by simply modifying your code:

```
newDT <- merge(x = DT, y = DTy, by = c("yr"))
# get names of columns with breakpoints
cnames <- names(newDT)[grep("^V", names(newDT))]

# apply the cut function by year. 
res <- newDT[, group := cut(ratio, unlist(.SD[1]), labels = F),
             by = .(yr), .SDcols = cnames][
                 , .(yr, id, ratio, group)]

#          yr    id     ratio cutted
# 1: 1962 10001  6.689275      6
# 2: 1962 10002  4.718753      4
# 3: 1962 10003  5.786855      5
# 4: 1962 10004  7.896540      7
# 5: 1962 10005  7.776863      7
# ---                            
# 53996: 2015 10996 10.613272     NA
# 53997: 2015 10997 11.260932     NA
# 53998: 2015 10998  8.591909      8
# 53999: 2015 10999  9.143039      9
# 54000: 2015 11000  7.470945      7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method using a join and `by=.EACHI`:

```
DT[DTy, on="yr",
   cutted := cut(ratio, c(i.V1, i.V2, i.V3, i.V4, i.V5, i.V6, i.V7, i.V8, i.V9, i.V10),
                 labels=FALSE), by=.EACHI]
```

Here, the data.table with the breaks is joined to the main data.table by year, then a new variable is assigned with `:=` using cut. This is applied to separately each group to which the values are joined using `by=.EAHCHI`.

This returns

```
head(DT)
     yr    id    ratio cutted
1: 1962 10001 6.689275      6
2: 1962 10002 4.718753      4
3: 1962 10003 5.786855      5
4: 1962 10004 7.896540      7
5: 1962 10005 7.776863      7
6: 1962 10006 6.566604      6
```

You can use `mget` and `ls` with a pattern search to eliminate the need to enumerate the variables used in the breaks argument in `cut`.

```
DT[DTy, on="yr", cutted := cut(ratio, c(mget(ls(pattern="^i\\.V\\d+$"))), labels=FALSE),
   by=.EACHI]
```